# Ansible: Check (GET) before Applying (POST/PUT) if applying is idempotent

Tags: rest, ansible, idempotent

I am writing roles in ansible, which use the ansible.builtin.uri method to do my bidding against the api of the service.
As I don't want to POST/PUT every time I run the Playbook, I check if the item I want to create already exists.
Does this make sense? In the end I introduce an extra step to GET the status, to skip the POST/PUT, where the POST/PUT itself would simply set what I want in the end.

For example, I wrote an Ansible Role which gives a User a role in Nexus.
Every time I run the Role, it first checks if the User already has the role and if not, it provides it.
If I don't check before and the User would already have the Role, it would simply apply it again.

But as I would like to know exactly whats going to happen, I believe it is better to explicitly check before applying.

What is the best practice for my scenario and are there any reasons against checking before or directly applying the changes?

Comment: "_Are there any reasons against checking before_", sure., there are. In example IOps, network traffic, bandwith, resource consumption, system load, etc. It should be in your own interest to have as least REST API calls as possible and to have just one or single call (interaction) in which you make sure that there is the desired state.

Comment: You will have to do the check (GET), either way if you want to have a proper return (OK when the GET returns something or CHANGED when you have to POST/PUT) and if you want to implement the check capacities on your role.

Comment: (disclaimer: i'm the author of the following role) - For users in nexus, I do this a bit differently. I actually use [a groovy script](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/main/files/groovy/setup_users_from_list.groovy) to which I pass a list of user configurations. The script returns details for each user in json result which is checked by [a custom filter](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/main/filter_plugins/nexus3_oss_filters.py) inside the [relevant task](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/main/tasks/call_script.yml) which reports ok/changed